# Blender Fluid Simulation With Moving Container

Tags: animation, rigging, fluid-simulation, collision

For this project, I'm trying to have a rigged character move while holding a bottle (simply parented to the hand bone).

I see many posts on this website referring to issues with fluid sims that are eventually resolved by someone telling them their normals are flipped, or they have to add thickness.

That doesn't appear to be the case in my scenario since my object has a natural thickness that I even increased in the Effector parameters. If the thickness *is* the problem, is there some way I'm supposed to up the quality of the simulation or scale-up my scene so it detects a smaller thickness? And if this isn't the case, is there something I'm missing that they don't tell you in the youtube tutorials?

I'd rather avoid turning up the resolution any higher considering I've got a fairly new gaming laptop with pretty dang high specs and setting the res to 150 resulted in a bluescreen.

[image]

Ver.: 3.0.0
Date of Issue: 2/27/22

Blend File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oyt4n9maxtgw3qw/FluidRigDemo.blend?dl=0

Comment: without seeing any of your settings and not knowing what you models/geometry looks like, we can just guess. So please provide blend file so we can check it out.

Comment: @Chris I had it set up, completely forgot to add it to the post though, sorry for the trouble. Should be updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although you don't wanna hear it...it is a resolution problem. If i raise your resolution to 300, i got:

[image]

so it is better...but not perfect.

or you take resolution 200 but use these collision settings for your bottle:

[image]

so you get this (i stopped at frame 14 because i was impatient) but until there it worked.

Comment: welp, knowing the source of the issue is better than nothing. Let’s just hope the issues from before were purely coincidental. Thank you for letting me know